# How can I call the API in my Appery.io Ionic 5 application?

Tags: ionic-framework, appery.io

I am using Appery.io online builder and could you please tell me how can I call the API in my Ionic 5 application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to send requests directly to the API from your application https://docs.appery.io/docs/appbuilder-jqm-advanced-client-services or using Server Code https://docs.appery.io/docs/servercode-overview or API Express REST component https://docs.appery.io/docs/apiexpress-visual-service-builder-rest-component